# How to update the value of the field in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document as follows in mongodb:

```
{
 "_id":"563f480fb5c2187503eefc1a",
 "ownerBy":"56335521f2f4a3150349d78d",
 "data":   {
   "username1":"76561198060520554",
   "username2":"76561198060520554",
   "username3":"76561198060520554",
   "username4":"76561198060520554",
   "username5":"76561198060520554"
  }, 
 "__v":0
}
```

The client wants to update the value of `username1` to the following `newValue`:

```
{ newValue: 'as76561198060520554',
  id: 'username1',
  column: 'selectable' 
}
```

How can I find the field `_id` and replace that with `newValue`?

Comment: Have you looked at [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-introduction/#update) on updating documents?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried first. We are not here to do your coding for you.

Answer (score 0):

Given the little information we have, this could possibly be what you're looking for!

Collection would be the name of your collection!

```
Collection.update({
"_id":"563f480fb5c2187503eefc1a"
},
{$rename: {"_id" : "newValue"}},
{$set: { 
newValue: 'as76561198060520554',

id: 'username1',
column: 'selectable' 
}},
{"upsert": true});
```